# How to add custom CSP Header in JBOSS using httpd.conf file

Tags: java, apache, jboss

I am trying to add response header Content security policy in JBoss environment using `httpd.conf` file but, I am not able to found any changes in the application.  I tried to set header using following code:

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';" 

add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self';";
```

Answer (score 0):

## Servlet

If you are processing requests from a servlet then add the header to the response object in the appropriate method (i.e. doGet, doPost ... ).

```
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
  throws ServletException, IOException 
  {

    response.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self';");
    // ...
  }
```

## JSF

If you are using JSF then create a filter and configure it in your web.xml file

```
public class SecurityFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter
{

@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain)
                throws IOException, ServletException
{
    HttpServletResponse httpRes = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    httpRes.setHeader("Content-Security-Policy", "default-src 'self';");


    // Continue the chain.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}

}
```

Sample entries to add to web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter </filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.blah.blah.SecurityFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>FacesServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```